# How to use ServerWebExchange.getMultipartData

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm writing global filter in spring cloud gateway. Trying to read request body in `multipart/form-data` type.
I've tried this:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestFilter implements GlobalFilter {

    private String loginId = "123456789";
    private String token = "987654321";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> multipartData = exchange.getMultipartData();
        return multipartData.flatMap(d -> {
            String loginIdVal = ((FormFieldPart) d.getFirst("loginId")).value();
            String tokenVal = ((FormFieldPart) d.getFirst("token")).value();

            log.info("loginIdVal: {}, tokenVal: {}", loginIdVal, tokenVal);

            return loginIdVal.equals(loginId) && tokenVal.equals(token)
                    ? chain.filter(exchange)
                    : Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Not match"));
        });

    }

}
```

But it always only works one time after I start the app. Then the exception appeared:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
```

I understand the request body can only be read once. But I didn't read body twice and why the exception always appeared from second execution?

Comment: Same problem, and `ServerWebExchage#getFormData` works fine.

Comment: If I use the GET method to request, will reproduce your problem, if I use the POST method to request, then the request will be stuck, refer to: [Cache body for form requests · Issue #1587 · spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1587)